# AWS CloudWatch Custom metric batching

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I read an article about [batching putMetric](https://engineering.mixmax.com/blog/batching-cloudwatch-metrics) operations, which seems quite cost efficient in theory, but their [suggested implementation](https://github.com/mixmaxhq/cloudwatch-metrics) is Node.js based and, we are looking for a Java approach but, I haven't been able to find any info on such topic, would anyone care to point me in the right direction please?

The simplest scenario we'd like to cover is a case where we must send two metrics, one after another, very often. So in this case, if we managed to actually merge/batch both putMetric operations/requests into a single one, their costs should drop to about a half.

Both [SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-cloudwatch-publish-custom-metrics.html) and [Javadoc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/AmazonCloudWatchClient.html#putMetricData-com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.PutMetricDataRequest-) for [Cloudwatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) just provide simple examples and, from those batching doesn't seem actually possible.

Answer (score 2):

As the [Javadoc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/model/PutMetricDataRequest.html#setMetricData-java.util.Collection-) shows, you could use `setMetricData` to set a collection of `MetricDatum`(no more than 20, they said), that's how batch works.

The [cloudwatch-metrics](https://github.com/mixmaxhq/cloudwatch-metrics/blob/master/index.js) uses the same magic [here](https://github.com/mixmaxhq/cloudwatch-metrics/blob/f1438181087146482a1d76ab15cf217f4b2703d3/index.js#L226) and [here](https://github.com/mixmaxhq/cloudwatch-metrics/blob/f1438181087146482a1d76ab15cf217f4b2703d3/index.js#L232).

Comment: Aha! You seem to be right, the only caveat I see is that all metrics must be from the same namespace but, I guess that might be worked out by the team. I'll came back later after we test the code